# error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript why

Tags: c++, arrays

This my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[10][10]= {0,0};
    int t,i,j,n,a,b,c,d;

    cin>>n;
    for(t=1;t<=n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a>>b>>c>>d;
        if((arr[a+1][b+1]==arr[c][d])||(arr[a+2][b+2]==arr[c][d])||(arr[a+3][b+3]==arr[c][d])||(arr[a+4][b+4]==arr[c][d])||(arr[a+5][b+5]==arr[c][d])||(arr[a+6][b+6]==arr[c][d])||(a[a+7][b+7]==a[c][d]))
        {
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        }
        else if(arr[a-1][b-1]==arr[c][d]||arr[a-2][b-2]==arr[c][d]||arr[a-3][b-3]==arr[c][d]||arr[a-4][b-4]==arr[c][d]||arr[a-5][b-5]==arr[c][d]||arr[a-6][b-6]==arr[c][d]||a[a-7][b-7]==a[c][d])
        {
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        }
        else if(arr[a-1][b+1]==arr[c][d]||arr[a-2][b+2]==arr[c][d]||arr[a-3][b+3]==arr[c][d]||arr[a-4][b+4]==arr[c][d]||arr[a-5][b+5]==arr[c][d]||arr[a-6][b+6]==arr[c][d]||a[a-7][b+7]==a[c][d])
        {
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        }
        else if(arr[a+1][b-1]==arr[c][d]||arr[a+2][b-2]==arr[c][d]||arr[a+3][b-3]==arr[c][d]||arr[a+4][b-4]==arr[c][d]||arr[a+5][b-5]==arr[c][d]||arr[a+6][b-6]==arr[c][d]||a[a+7][b-7]==a[c][d])
        {
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<"NO"<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Code Blocks show me error:

```
invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
```

I don't understand why this type error occur.

Comment: Never #include <bits/stdc++.h> directy, include what you use instead. This case, <iostreams>.  Also, please post a minimal example, and mark the line which produces the error.

Comment: yes i will try. thanks for your valuable advise

Comment: Also see [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2):

`a[a+7][b+7]==a[c][d]`

You use `a` instead of `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

Please note you have used

```
a[a+7][b-7] instead of arr[a+7][b-7]
```

in last conditions of all your if statements. That is why it's throwing that error as
'a' in your case is an int and you trying to find a[a+7][b-7] => int[int][int]

Also at the end you have just written

```
cout<"NO"<<endl;
```

it should be

```
cout<<"NO"<<endl; // note the two angular brackets
```